# Creating a function which creates a vector without needing quotation marks for strings

Tags: r, function, vector

I know that `dplyr` select has the ability to subset a dataset using column names without quotation marks:

```
function (.data, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("select")
}
```

I would like to do something similar, but instead of subsetting, I want the function to create a vector. Something like:

```
var_select <- function (...) {
    UseMethod("select")
}
vector  <-var_select(cyl, disp, hp)
> vector
[1] "cyl"  "disp" "hp"
```

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
foo <- function(...){
  as.character(as.list(match.call()[-1L]))
}

> foo(a,b,c)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

`deparse()` can be a bit safer than `as.character()`, and maybe it's a bit clearer to use the `...` rather than the call itself, we'd get :

```
v <- function(...){
  sapply(eval(substitute(alist(...))), deparse)
}
v(a,b,list(1))
#> [1] "a"       "b"       "list(1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = function(...){
    unname(sapply(rlang::enexprs(...), as.character))
}
foo(cyl, disp, hp)
#[1] "cyl"  "disp" "hp"
```